# Converting xls to csv in Python 3 using xlrd

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, xlrd

I'm using Python 3.3 with xlrd and csv modules to convert an xls file to csv. This is my code:

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('MySpreadsheet.xls')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('test_output.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):

        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()
```

With that I am receiving this error: `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface`

I tried changing the encoding and replaced the line within the loop with this:

```
wr.writerow(bytes(sh.row_values(rownum),'UTF-8'))
```

But I get this error: `TypeError: encoding or errors without a string argument`

Anyone know what may be going wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Try this

```
import xlrd
import csv

def csv_from_excel():
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook('MySpreadsheet.xlsx')
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
    your_csv_file = open('output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in range(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

i recommend using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) library for this task

```
import pandas as pd
xls = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
df = xls.parse(sheetname="Sheet1", index_col=None, na_values=['NA'])
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is basically that you open your file with Python2 semantics. Python3 is locale-aware, so if you just want to write text to this file (and you do), open it as a text file with the right options:

`your_csv_file = open('test_output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='')`

The encoding parameter specifies the output encoding (it does not have to be utf-8) and the Python3 documentation for csv expressly says that you should specify `newline=''` for csv file objects.

Answer (score 2):

A quicker way to do it with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd

xls_file = pd.read_excel('MySpreadsheet.xls', sheetname="Sheet1")
xls_file.to_csv('MySpreadsheet.csv', index = False)
#remove the index because pandas automatically indexes the first column of CSV files.
```

You can read more about pandas.read_excel [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html).