# Python read xlsx as Csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using xlrd to read a xlsx file as a csv. For this purpose I'm using the following code:

```
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("170519_taxonomy_in_qiime.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
source_data = [sheet.row_values(rowx) for rowx in range(sheet.nrows)]
```

Which gives me this example result

```
[[225145.0, 'k__Bacteria', ' p__ZB3', ' c__Rs-J96', ' o__', ' f__', ' g__', ' s__'], [2916972.0, 'k__Bacteria', ' p__ZB3', ' c__Rs-J96', 'o__', ' f__', ' g__', ' s__']]
```

But I need my result to look like this:

```
[['225145.0, k__Bacteria,  p__ZB3,  c__Rs-J96,  o__,  f__,  g__,  s__'], ['2916972.0, k__Bacteria,  p__ZB3,  c__Rs-J96,  o__,  f__,  g__,  s__']]
```

Any Idea how can do this?

Comment: How is the question related to the title? Just `join` the inner list to obtain the result...

Comment: If you're trying to convert your `xlsx` into a `csv` this might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688477/converting-xls-to-csv-in-python-3-using-xlrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each item in source_data is a list of values. You are trying to produce a single string containing each value in the list.

You can use the `str.join` function for this. However, note that the first element in the list is a float value and not a string, so you first need to convert that to a string before using the join function.

For example:

```
source_data = [' '.join(map(str,sheet.row_values(rowx))) for rowx in range(sheet.nrows)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [[225145.0, 'k__Bacteria', ' p__ZB3', ' c__Rs-J96', ' o__', ' f__', ' g__', ' s__'], [2916972.0, 'k__Bacteria', ' p__ZB3', ' c__Rs-J96', 'o__', ' f__', ' g__', ' s__']]

y = []
for c in x:
    b = ""
    for a in c:
        b =b + "".join(str(a))
    y.append(b)
y
```

Output

```
['225145.0k__Bacteria p__ZB3 c__Rs-J96 o__ f__ g__ s__',
 '2916972.0k__Bacteria p__ZB3 c__Rs-J96o__ f__ g__ s__']
```